# How to measure HTTP Latency with Percentile in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to plot percentile graphs of http backend time taken using prometheus query. But it returns **NaN**.

Giving some subqueries work but even if one values has NaN, sum returns Nan.

```
sum by (quantile) (http_duration_milliseconds{http_status_code=~"[23]"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Quantiles will be NaN if there were no recent queries, similar to how `total time of queries/number of queries` would be NaN.

It's also incorrect to sum quantiles, or perform any other aggregation on them, as that makes no statistical sense. If you want an aggregated quantile, use the Prometheus Histogram type.